# Pulseaudio cannot load module after kernel upgrade

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, pulseaudio

I have upgraded my kernel to `4.15.8-300.fc27.x86_64` and again, it was a bad idea. My system is completely unstable. :(

One of the things is that I have no found inside firefox. Whenever I start Firefox on youtube or so I get this in syslog:

```
Mar 19 08:21:59 andromeda.desktop pulseaudio[3911]: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: inotify_init1() failed: Function not implemented
Mar 19 08:21:59 andromeda.desktop pulseaudio[3911]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-udev-detect" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
Mar 19 08:21:59 andromeda.desktop pulseaudio[3911]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Mar 19 08:21:59 andromeda.desktop pulseaudio[3911]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Mar 19 08:21:59 andromeda.desktop pulseaudio[3907]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Pulseaudio is trying to use `inotify` and failing. The error message suggests the feature is not available, which suggests a mistake in kernel configuration.

Let's compare your upgraded kernel with any older kernel versions you may still have installed. What does

```
grep -i inotify /boot/config-*
```

say? Are all options including the keyword INOTIFY set the same in your new kernel as in any older ones?

---

If there is no difference in kernel configuration, then the reason must be elsewhere. [A bit of googling indicates this error message can also appear when the session D-Bus is not available.](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=262962)

What desktop environment are you using, and how are you starting it? Are you using the distribution's defaults, or are you using a customized environment? Are you using a GUI login dialog (as produced by `gdm` or some other `*dm`), or using something like `startx` to start your GUI sessions?

Comment: The other alternative is true, Fedora comes with inotify compiled in for all versions:
/boot/config-4.15.7-300.fc27.x86_64:CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y
/boot/config-4.15.8-300.fc27.x86_64:CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y
/boot/config-4.15.9-300.fc27.x86_64:CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will confirm what might be happening with dbus. I am using a custom Fedora27 with i3 and lightdm. Thanks for the tip, will come back with results.